# Can anyone identify this early 20th century uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

Maybe US, British or Irish.  Might be military or civil. Early 20th century.  Medals on right chest?  Commemorative or mirror image?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a higher resolution version of the image?

Comment: Can you either get a clearer picture of the eagle on the cover, or else describe which way the eagle's head is facing?  Do you have provenance?  Is the collar asymmetrical?? Looks like there is an insignia on the left but not on the right?  Any of those would help to verify whether it is mirror image.

Answer (score 1):

It's the officer's fly-fronted undress tunic for commissioned officers in the US navy that was worn until the end of world war one. No idea if it's mirror image or commemorative; although the former sounds more likely.

Comment: Looks more like a US Army cap device rather than US Navy.